# How many does the parent node have child node?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

```
<form id="frm1">
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
</form>
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction();" value="Göster"/>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        var x = document.getElementById("frm1");

        document.write(x.length); // 2 (!) Why?
        document.write(x.childNodes.length); // 5 (!) Why?
    }
</script>
```

1. x.childNodes[0] == first input tag inside form, isn't it?
2. x.childNodes[1] == second input tag inside form, isn't it?

But the second document.write statement prints number 5. Ok, the two child is above. Well, what is the next three elements? According to w3schools, x.length statement means child number of frm1. But I know from XML lessons in  w3schools again that x.length doesn't mean child number of "frm1" or "anything". Namely:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        // --------------------- XML DOCUMENT PARSER -------------------------------
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","books.xml",false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------


        x=xmlDoc.getElementById("first"); // first is an id of XML tag


        document.write(x.length + "<br>"); // Output: Undefined
        document.write(x.childNodes.length); // Output : 9

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are xml codes. That is, you can check xml file to understand the code beneath.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
    <book id="first" category="COOKING">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

If you try run penultimate code snippet in a browser, x.length in penultimate code snippet above outputs "undefined". Does it make sense? I think yes. Then, x.childNodes.length in penultimate code snippet above outputs number 9. That is why there is 4 element nodes and 4 text nodes plus 1 attribute node inside the book element. Total is 9. Why isn't there this situtation in the following?

```
<form id="frm1">
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
</form>
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction();" value="Göster"/>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        var x = document.getElementById("frm1");

        document.write(x.length); // 2 ? It must be undefined(!)
        document.write(x.childNodes.length); // 5 ? It must be 2(!)
    }
</script>
```

document.write(x.length) involves printing undefined instead of 2, doesn't it?
document.write(x.childNodes.length) involves printing number 2 instead of 5, doesn't it?

Could you explain these two question above, please?

Comment: `form`'s indexed properties contain only the elements within a form, `childNodes` contains all the nodes, including textnodes like new-lines and spacing chracters. [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) when called after the page has been parsed opens a new document, which wipes out all the previous code on a page (and shouldn't work in XML at all). Just don't use it for debugging, `console.log()` is for that purpose.

Comment: Well, Why is the x.length, which is related to xml tag, undefined. If x.length gives us elements within parent node, x.length involves not giving undefined. How can you explain this situtation?

Comment: You've stated yourself: "But I know from XML lessons in w3schools again that x.length doesn't mean child number of "frm1" or "anything"." XML is not HTML, and XML elements don't implement indexed properties.

Comment: OK. Thank you so much. The answer that I am searching is it. Thank you also for console.log().